# I am writing a mergesort3 function that is supposed to take an array of numbers or values and divide them into 3 separate arrays for sorting

Tags: python, arrays, merge, mergesort

I am having an issue with my code, as it will not execute and displays a `TypeError` message in the format:
`list indices must be integers or slices, not list`.

I believe that my mergesort function is functional, but I am not entirely sure.
I believe that the issue comes from the part of the code where I am trying to read from a file that contains lists of numbers that are unsorted.

```
with open(filelocation) as fl:
   line = fl.readline()
   while line:
       line = line.split()
        for i in range(1, len(line)):
           # converting read elements into integer values for sorting
            line[i] = int(line[i])
        input.append(line)
       line = fl.readline()
with open('merge3.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in input:
        mergeSort3(input[i], 0, 1 / 3 * len(input), 2 / 3 * len(input), len(input), input())
        print(input)
```

The error pops up on the last 2 lines of this code, or rather, the `mergeSort3` statement when I call the parameters of my initial function: `def mergeSort3(arr1, low, mid1, mid2, high, arr2)`.
I am also writing my code in Python, although that is probably not the issue. 
Any help is appreciated!

Essentially what I expect from this is to be able to open the file data.txt and read each of the values, and then sort that data via merge sort /3 (dividing the arrays into thirds) and write that data into a new text file called merge3.txt.

Comment: if you post the expectation stack here. it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you append `line` to `input`, `line` is a list of integers. Therefore, `input` is a list of lists.
When you loop through `input`, `i` will be one of those lists.
You then attempt to index `input` with the list. Hence the error telling you that you can't use a list as an index.

Comment: Alright, I see what you mean now. Do you have any hints that you can give me based on what I have given? I am stuck on what I need to be calling.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're attempting to do.

Comment: Essentially what I am trying to do in this program is to make a merge sort that divides the array into thirds, so basically having 3 different arrays. My code is where I am trying to open a file that has several lists of numbers that should be sorted via the merge sort / 3 function. Then once that file is being read, I want to be able to write to a different file with the output or sorted list contained in it, and I have called it merge3.txt. I want to be able to grab the 3 different arrays being: 1/3 of the list, another with 2/3 of the list and lastly the end 3/3 of the list and merge them

Comment: I meant specifically where you're attempting to index the list with another list.